# Compact Way To Shear Dictionary With Tuple For Key in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I don't think this is a duplicate, but I just might not be using the correct terminology in my searching.  My apologies if this is the case.

What I have is a dictionary mapping a tuple (custom object, string) to a float.  To be exact then, it is a 2-tuple.  What I am trying to do is get back a representation of all entries in the dictionary that match on the custom object.

Example:

```
mydict[(co1, 'hello')] = 0.01
mydict[(co2, 'bye')] = 0.02
```

Where co1 and co2 are supposed to represent two distinct custom objects.  I want to find all entries that contain co1 (it's logical equivalent) in the tuple which is the key.

So my question then is how to reduce this 2_tuple=>float dictionary down to a string=>float dictionary when the string is the unique (non-matched) tuple.

What I have tried:

```
for custom in custom_object:
    for k, v in mydict.iteritems():
        if custom in k:
           #store this particular entry into another data structure or otherwise process
```

Comment: What is the algorithm that links the tuple to the value? - Is it arbitrary?

Comment: @user1438003 - It is data driven.  I am scoring the combination of a word and an object co-occurring in some test documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use unpacking in a comprehension:

```
dict((s, v) for (o, s), v in mydict.iteritems() if o is co1)
```

From Python 2.7:

```
{s: v for (o, s), v in mydict.iteritems() if o is co1}
```

Comment: That appears to do the trick.  It just took me like a minute to wrap my mind around what the code is doing.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you are trying to do will become very inefficient as the corpus[?] increases in size.

Maybe what you want to do instead is hash `[0]` **and** `[1]` into a third allotment: `[2]` which is to be stored in a dictionary.

Then to simply store an array of pointers (I know it's python, but you this is easy enough to implement with duplication) on the fourth allotment of the tuple `[3]`.

By keeping an auxiliary structure storing if tuples have `[3]` populated (and possible their count), you will be able to perform these queries in almost guaranteed O(1):

1. **Enumerate all repeats**
2. **Enumerate 0.01 appearance or None**
3. **Is what I'm inserting a duplicate?**

Enjoy `:]`